# Stripe / Rails Issue: "Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm building a custom checkout form in my rails app and getting this error when posting to the controller:

"Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string"

Here's my form:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

    <%= form_tag registrations_path, :id=>"stripeForm" do |f| %>
      <h2>Register for the <%= @workshop.name %> Workshop ($<%= @workshop.price %>)</h2>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <%= text_field_tag(:f_name, nil, :placeholder=>"First Name", :class=>"form-control") %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <%= text_field_tag(:l_name, nil, :placeholder=>"Last Name", :class=>"form-control") %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
         <button class="buy-button" id="stripe-button">Buy Ticket</button>
         <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeToken' %>
         <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeEmail' %>
         <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeAmount' %>
      </div>

       <script>
     var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
       key: "<%= ENV['stripe_publishable_key'] %>",
       token: function (token, args) {
         $("#stripeToken").value = token.id;
         $("#stripeEmail").value = token.email;
         $("#stripeAmount").value = <%= @workshop.price * 100 %>;
         $("#stripeForm").submit();
       }
     });

     $('#stripe-button').on('click', function (e) {
       // Open Checkout with further options
       $name = $('input[name=f_name]').val() + " " + $('input[name=l_name]').val();
       handler.open({
         name: $name,
         description: "<%= @workshop.name %>" + " workshop",
         amount: <%= @workshop.price * 100 %>
       });
     e.preventDefault();
     });

     $(window).on('popstate', function() {
       handler.close();
     });
   </script>

    <% end %>
```

Here's my controller action:

```
def create
    # Amount in cents
    amount = params[:stripeAmount].to_i * 100

    # Create the customer in Stripe
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: params[:stripeEmail],
      card: params[:stripeToken]
    )

    # Create the charge using the customer data returned by Stripe API
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer: customer.id,
      amount: amount,
      description: 'Rails Stripe customer',
      currency: 'usd'
    )

    # place more code upon successfully creating the charge
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path
    flash[:notice] = "Please try again"
  end
```

Basically the user fills out first and last name, clicks on pay button. Then they fill out stripe info and submit. I've tried using debugger right after they click submit, and all the token info etc is there as it should be.

But then I get an error as soon as it gets to the create action in the controller, and shows empty strings for all the stripe params.

Where am I going wrong?

Edit: added below strong params to the controller but had no effect:

```
protected

  def registration_params
    params.require(:registration).permit(:stripeEmail, :stripeToken, :stripeAmount)
  end
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?  If Rails 4+, you should be white listing what you need from the `params` hash in a helper function.

Comment: Hmmm.. So I added strong_params to my controller and got the exact same errors (and params still blank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a minor issue with your jQuery. The token is there, but it doesn't look like its being submitted through the form. That should be the reason Stripe is complaining about an empty string. Try this instead:

```
$("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
$("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
$("#stripeAmount").val('<%= j @workshop.price * 100 %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises only when you try to update the user subscription but the payment source is not attached with the Stripe customer.

If you are trying to update subscription from `Trial` to `Paid` then please take a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64816287/8247133) which may helps you out.